# How to render messages without refreshing the page in chat engine

Tags: react-chat-engine

I built a chat app using react chat engine but i always need to refresh the page to render received messages and I'm not getting the typing message also. When i cheked the console i'm getting the following error.

xhr.js:177     POST https://api.chatengine.io/chats/205898/typing/ 429 (Too Many Requests)

This is my code

```
import { signOut } from 'firebase/auth'
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { ChatEngine } from 'react-chat-engine'
import { auth } from '../firebase.config'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext'
import axios from 'axios'

const Chats = () => {

    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    console.log(ChatEngine);
    const handleLogout = async() => {
        await signOut(auth);
        navigate('/');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!user) {
            navigate('/')
            return;
        }
        axios.get('https://api.chatengine.io/users/me/', {
            headers: {
                "project-id": "69ad2362-2ec9-40e5-863a-da98bfb94565",
                "user-name": user.email,
                "user-secret": user.uid 
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch(() => { 
            axios.post('https://api.chatengine.io/users/',
                {
                    "username": user.email,
                    "secret": user.uid,
                },
                {headers: { "PRIVATE-KEY": "59b46f17-b1ca-453a-8580-594e6bb8b31a" }}
            )
            .then(() => setLoading(false))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error))
        })
    }, [user, navigate])

    if(!user || loading) return (<button onClick={handleLogout}>logout</button>);

    return (
        <div className="chats-page">
            <div className="nav-bar">
                <div className="logo-tab">Unichat</div>
                <div 
                    onClick={handleLogout}
                    className="logout-tab"
                >
                    Logout
                </div>
            </div>
            <ChatEngine
                height="clac(100vh - 66px)"
                projectID="69ad2362-2ec9-40e5-863a-da98bfb94565"
                userName={user.email}
                userSecret={user.uid}
            />
        </div>
  )
}

export default Chats
```